# Args in environment

Tags: environments

I'm trying to create an environment. The error is as follows, the passed argument is not on the same line as the word Theorem. The result of the code below is

Theorem 1.1.1 [

The desired result would be

Theorem 1.1.1 (I do this)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}  
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  ENVIROMENTS  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{framed}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}[2][\hsize]
{
    \def\FrameCommand
    {
        {\color{#2}\vrule width 3pt}
        \hspace{1pt}
    }
    \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}
}
{\endMakeFramed}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ENVIROMENT THEOREM  %%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcounter{myteocounter}
\counterwithin{myteocounter}{section}

\newenvironment{myteo}[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}\refstepcounter{myteocounter}\leftbar{black} \hspace*{-\dimexpr\parindent+15pt} \colorbox{black}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily Teorema \themyteocounter\ #1}\smallskip\par\noindent}%
{\endleftbar}

\begin{document}    

\chapter{Some Chapter}
\section{Some Section}

\begin{myteo}[I do this]
\lipsum[1]
\end{myteo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably it would be easier to do  with `mdframed` : it defines `\newmdtheoremenv` and cooperates with `ntheorem` via an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that your `myteo` environment takes a mandatory argument and no optional argument, but you are only trying to pass an optional one. As a consequence, the actual mandatory argument of `myteo` receives what comes next and is brace-balanced in the input following `\begin{myteo}`, which is a single `[` character token: the one that starts `[I do this]` (but please realize that `[I do this]` is *not* considered as an argument by your `myteo` environment—only `[` is; this is the same as if you had written `\begin{myteo}{[}I do this] (...)`). Then the remaining `I do this]` tokens become part of the environment body, and you indeed find them at the beginning of your theorem text!

[image: Bad]

So, you essentially need to fix the argument declaration for `myteo`:

```latex
\newenvironment{myteo}[1][]{...}{...}
```

(this assumes you want to have one optional argument whose default value is empty). You can act differently based on whether this argument is blank or not using `\ifblank` from the `etoolbox` package, as done below. I also improved a few things that are generally desirable for such environments (added `\ignorespaces`, `\unskip`, `\ignorespacesafterend`); I also added `%` characters to avoid supurious spaces in the definition of environment `leftbar`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}[2][\hsize]
{%
    \def\FrameCommand
    {%
        {\color{#2}\vrule width 3pt}%
        \hspace{1pt}%
    }%
    \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
}
{\endMakeFramed}

\newcounter{myteocounter}
\counterwithin{myteocounter}{section}

\newenvironment{myteo}[1][]{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}%
  \refstepcounter{myteocounter}%
  \begingroup
  \leftbar{black}%
  \hspace*{-\dimexpr\parindent+15pt}%
  \colorbox{black}{%
     \color{white}\bfseries\sffamily Teorema \themyteocounter
     \ifblank{#1}{}{ (#1)}%
  }%
  \smallskip\par\noindent
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \unskip
  \endleftbar
  \endgroup
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\begin{document}

\section{Some Section}

\begin{myteo}[I do this]
\lipsum[1]
\end{myteo}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of fixed code]

Comment: I made a small adjustment to align the left bar and it was perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! :-)